# Webpack Babel-loader transpiles code with eval()

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I'm having an issue with Webpack and Babel. I'm trying transpile my JavaScript code into a bundle file. Here's the file structure and the snippets:

**file structure:**

```
- src
| file.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "babel-webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/file.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['env']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I enter `webpack --mode development`, it creates the file `app.bundle.js` successfully inside the directory `build`.

[image]

However, it doesn't seem to be working properly, because at the end of `build/app.bundle.js` where I'm looking for the code from `src/file.js` I have the following :

```
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\n\nvar fun = function fun() {\n  return console.log('Hello World');\n};\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/file.js?");

/***/ })
```

Which is strange, am I not supposed to simply have this instead?

```
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
let fun = () => console.log('Hello World')

/***/ })
```

Is there a problem with the config?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually not because of babel, but because of webpack. It requires an option called `devtool` that decides whether it should `eval` the code or use some sort of source-map.

You might be looking for the following:

```
// webpack.config.js (excerpt)
module.exports = {
    // ...
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    // ...
};
```

The `inline-source-map` omits eval in favor of a - well - inlined sourcemap inside the bundle. Do not use it for production, though ;-)

There are several options for `devtool` that all have their advantages and disadvantages. For more information on the topic, please refer to the [official webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).

Answer (score 5):

After countless hours of research, I finally found the solution, the preset that needs to be used is `babel-preset-env` and **not `env`**.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/file.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['babel-preset-env'] // <-- here
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be guessing but can you not also use a .babelrc?

Comment: @ColinD Yes you can